# Badge number is always displayed as 1

Tags: cordova, uilocalnotification

I am using [iOS PhoneGap local notification plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).

I have scheduled a daily repeated notification at 08:30. The badge number is always displayed as 1, even after I uninstall and re-install the app or comment out the `window.plugin.notification.local.add({})`. Checking on the notification board, both 'all' and 'missing' are empty. Any idea?

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        date: d, // This expects a date object
        message: itemsData4.newsItems[0].headline, // The message that is displayed
        title: 'Morning Food Delivered', // The title of the message
        repeat: 'daily', // Either 'secondly', 'minutely', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly' or 'yearly'
        autoCancel: true, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the badge number is only updated when explicitly told to do so. So you could try `window.plugin.notification.local.cancelAll()` and then add a fresh one with `date:new Date()` and `bagde:0`.